# web developer toolbar View Style Information missing

Tags: html, css, web-developer-toolbar

This is a screenshot of Web Developer Toolbar in Chrome. According to the book I am reading there should be View Style Information button in the CSS tab, but it isn't. Where is it hiding?

[image]

If I click View CSS I get some hard to inspect code shown here:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"View CSS" is an equivalent. I think the screenshot in your book is from an old version of the toolbar

Comment: If i click that I get some very hard to read and inspect code shown in the new screenshot. According to the book, it shouldn't look like that.

Comment: Click on the extension button, go to options/Options... and set the Syntax highlighting theme to Light. That should be more readable

Comment: that helped. Is it possible to show that window next to the page I am viewing? The book talks that the borders of elements should highlight when I hover over them.

Comment: The chrome developer window (press F12) can highlight border of elements when you hover them in the html code. I don't know how to do that with the toolbar.